# CSS isn't working in my Python/HTML project

Tags: html, css, pycharm

I'm working with Pycharm for the first time on a python/HTML project, and I can't get the CSS to work.

Both my CSS and HTML file are in the same folder in Pycharm — they're both in alpha/templates.

Here's Stylesheet.css:

```
h5 {
  color: #ff0000;
  }
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
      <head>
         <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
      </head>
   <body>
...
      <h5>
   Test CSS --- this should look red
      </h5>
   </body>
</html>
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if you're importing the css file correctly.
   Example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
  </head>
<body>
```

2. Check if the naming and the casing of the filename and the import are identical

`StyleSheet.css` is not the same with `styleSheet.css`

3. Check if the path is correct
4. If nothing works, try with an absolute path
5. Check if another style from the same or another css is file overwriting it, for example

```
body h5 {
 color: black;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! When I plugged in "https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css" instead of "StyleSheet.css," it did change the styles. So it must be a path issue. But using an absolute path doesn't seem to fix it, so I'm back to being confused ... Any ideas?

Comment: I need to see more. Please upload your whole project in github.

Comment: Thanks! I got it working --- I uploaded the .css file online and linked to it in my code. Still can't figure out why it can't read it in the directory  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯